# Mapping and Tracking in an android with google maps and receiving from a web server

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to develop a system that's able to map routes and track vehicles on the routes. The vehicles would be equipped with a raspberry pi and a gps module that would send the gps location long lat to a web server. From there I want to be able to show the mapped tracks and the position of the vehicle in an android phone. I want to show the approximate time of arrival of the vehicle to the next marker on the map.

It's like the uber interface of seeing the driver, it's path and the estimated time of arrival but with a fixed path that the tracked vehicle travels (it doesn't disappear) and the ETA for different markers on the map. What I'm trying to develop it's an app that can be used on android to facilitate travel in city busses. It shows the route and shows the bus ETA to the next bus stop (the marker).

Main questions:

- How do I recollect the long/lat from the server from the android app
  utilizing the google maps api?
- Should I take another approach to this? what do you suggest?
- Any suggestions changing the hardware (rpi with module) to another one?
- How do you recommend I should develop this?

Thanks for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar app, I used to send lat/long, time and id (one unique Id per bus) to my sql server. Then on the app I make a request on my server to get my data (I get a Json like this :

```
{lat:48.23,long:2.65,time:1488815476,id:F12B35}
```

So you have the location of your bus at the time t.
I don't recommand you a raspberry, i think an arduino would be better if ou want to send your data to your server by GSM/GPRS for example.

Comment: Thanks!. Btw can you indicate me some documentation or tell me what to look for so i can learn how to make the request for the data? (i'm pretty new to all this and haven't quite the knowledge)